# The CSS Rule object

Tags: javascript, css

According this site [externalcss3](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/externalcss3.shtml) The CSS Rule object of the styleSheet object lets you access the individual rules of a stylesheet.

So If I try to run this piece of code(*) on stackoverflow page, using the javascript console, I expect to see some CSS Rules written in this page http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=04e0337352b3.

(*)

```
var mysheet=document.styleSheets[0]
var myrules=mysheet.cssRules? mysheet.cssRules: mysheet.rules
for (i=0; i<myrules.length; i++) {
     console.log(myrules[i].selectorText.toLowerCase());
}
```

Actually the result of console.log is something different from what I would expect:

```
object[type="application/x-shockwave-flash"], object[type="application/futuresplash"], object[data*=".swf"], object[src*=".swf"], embed[type="application/x-shockwave-flash"], embed[type="application/futuresplash"], embed[src*=".swf"]
```

What have I Missed? Sorry for my ignorance and your time.

Comment: I actually find that there are no rules in the only stylesheet (0). Still weird.

Comment: (Or a security error in Firefox - even stranger!)

Comment: I bet the stylesheet you are seeing is being injected by a browser extension... something like adblock, maybe (except adblock puts the stylesheet at the end, so must be something else).

Answer (score 5):

It seems you can only access the rules in the CSS file if they are from the same domain.

Read this thread: [**Reading the rules of a cross domain CSS file in DOM**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122265/reading-the-rules-of-a-cross-domain-css-file-in-dom)

Comment: Definitely correct, although I am curious why the OP could read any rules at all.

Comment: @apsillers - I have no idea. I correctly get a TypeError: `Cannot read property 'length' of null`.